# How can I document randomly-assigned properties of a custom type in JSDoc?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

```js
/**
 * @typedef {string} UUID
 * */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ITEM
 * @property {UUID} id
 * */

/** 
 * @typedef {Object} THINGY
 * @property {??????}
 * */

const oneThingy = {
 asdf: {id: 'asdf', ...},
 sdfg: {id: 'sdfg', ...},
 dfgh: {id: 'dfgh', ...}
}
```

Assuming that a `THINGY` can have infinite k:v pairs, and that the keys will be random `UUID`s, how would I document and type the `@property`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a kind person named Kyriakos on the JSDoc Slack channel, TIL it's not the `@property`, I just need the properly-formatted `@typedef`:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {string} UUID
 * */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} ITEM
 * @property {UUID} id
 * */

/** 
 * @typedef {Object.<UUID, ITEM>} THINGY // <-- this one
 * */

const oneThingy = {
 asdf: {id: 'asdf', ...},
 sdfg: {id: 'sdfg', ...},
 dfgh: {id: 'dfgh', ...}
}
```